# Accessing Exchange Server using PHP

Tags: php, exchange-server

I am trying to access Windows Exchange Server using PHP. I found a class online that does the connection to the exchange server 
http://www.troywolf.com/articles/php/exchange_webdav_examples.php

The problem is when I try this code I get a syntax error and now sure how to solve it.

if you look at the first example

```
$h->xmlrequest = '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; 
$h->xmlrequest .= <<<END 
<a:searchrequest xmlns:a="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/security/"> 
   <a:sql> 
       SELECT "DAV:displayname" 
       FROM SCOPE('hierarchical traversal of "$exchange_server/Exchange/twolf/inbox"') 
   </a:sql> 
</a:searchrequest> 
END;
```

in the second line I get a syntax error and not sure how to solve it.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL
```

Also for the $exchange_server value do I put the web mail address? 
ex. https://exch2.myDomain.com/owa/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code must be looking like this:

```
$exchange_server = 'localhost';
$h->xmlrequest = '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; 
$h->xmlrequest .= <<<END
<a:searchrequest xmlns:a="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/security/"> 
   <a:sql> 
       SELECT "DAV:displayname" 
       FROM SCOPE('hierarchical traversal of "$exchange_server/Exchange/twolf/inbox"') 
   </a:sql> 
</a:searchrequest> 
END;
# !!! no more content after ; (spaces included, you had one) !!!

echo $h->xmlrequest;
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who may come across this issue, check for a trailing space after the `<<<END`